# Error returning SQL results via PHP into a html table

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm having issues with the below code, it returns the first two rows and then throws a sql exception error (see below). The first row returned has spaces, the second does not not and then the remaining 6 or 7 rows do not return. Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? The query works ok if I excecute in management studio.

Thanks

```
$TraceDBCon = mssql_connect("dbaddress", "username", "password") or die("Couldn't connect to SQL DB");

$result = mssql_query ("select loadindex, PalletNo1, PalletNo2, PalletNo3, PalletNo4 from [LoadManifest].[dbo].LM_Lines
where LMHeaderID = $LMHeaderID
order by loadindex asc", $TraceDBCon);

echo "<table>";
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['loadindex'] . "</td><td>" . $row['PalletNo1'] . "</td><td>" . $row['PalletNo2'] . "</td><td>" . $row['PalletNo3'] . "</td><td>" . $row['PalletNo4'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";



1 15322832 15322832 15322832 15322832 
219758646197586461975864619758646
Warning: mssql_fetch_array(): 3 is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\filename.php on line 52
```

Comment: which is line 52 in your code?

Comment: Side notes: you're missing the } after your while loop. Also DON'T USE mssql_, same reason as mysql_, it's removed in php 7. Use PDO instead.

Comment: while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)){

Comment: Seph, that was exactly the problem thank you.